hierarchical filter spring data jpa jpql
I have entity in spring boot project
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "products", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "idx_product_name", columnList = "name"),
        @Index(name = "idx_product_article", columnList = "name")
})
public class ProductEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    private String  name;
    private String article;
    private double price;
    private String  description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private CategoryEntity category; //<------

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private  List<ProductImageEntity> images;
    private String main_image_url;

    
}

in which i have foreign field  category of CategoryEntity entity with
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "idx_categories_name", columnList = "name")
})
public class CategoryEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    private String  name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private CategoryEntity parent;//<------
}

and as you can notice category entity is hierarchical for example:
Category1
 Category2
   Category3
    ...so on

and products list can be like this:
Category1
 Category2
   Category3
    Product1
    Product2
    Product3
  Category4
    Product4
    Product5
    Product6

Question how to make query with jpql by category
I can do like this :
select t from ProductEntity t where category.id =:category
Where I fill category parameter with value of the category  lowest hierarchical level (for example Category4 or Category3)
but how can I get products with category with higher hierarchical level Category2 or Category1?
in my logic if i filter by Category1 then all products belonging to Category1 must retrieve from db
explanation or code example
